# What is the preferred alternative to the deprecated Primefaces Layout component

Tags: primefaces

Looking at the Primefaces Showcase it looks like the Layout component is deprecated. Here is link : https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/layout/element.xhtml

So if I want to create a template that will have header, body and footer what Primefaces component should we be using now?

thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: No component... It was overkill (unless you needed the open/close which many people did not) use plain html and css....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar component in PrimeFaces extensions: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/layout.jsf

it is based on the same Jquery Layout component however I agree with @Kukeltje you should only use this component if you need to the open/close capability.  If not, using straight CSS is probably your better longer term option.